# Is it safe to store supabase session access token in streamlit session state?

Tags: python, token, browser-cache, streamlit, supabase

I am using supabase authentication system for my streamlit app which is a multipage app. One page is the login and another page display the data of the logged in user.

To retrieve the user in the page with data I have to store in session-state the token of the logged in user.

In my login.py I Have:

```
user = supabase.auth.sign_in_with_password({"email": email, "password": password})
st.session_state["token"] = supabase.auth.get_session().access_token
```

and in my data page I retrieve the user like this:

```
user = supabase.auth.get_user(st.session_state["token"])
```

Could you please tell me what you think ? I would like to know if this us unsafe or not.

Many thanks for reading me.